# c_initialize - this object is not connected to a module

Tags: c#, .net, smartcard, smartcard-reader

I am trying to use a smartcard. I am using bunch of libraries. When the smartcard library tries to create an instance it gives me this error : "c_initialize - this object is not connected to a module". I used both winform and web form applications in .net . The error pops up at this line :

```
Pair<long, CardType> slotAndCardType = SmartOp.getSlotAndCardType(terminal);
```

Comment: I suspect this error comes from one of the "bunch of libraries" you are referencing. Googling that error comes up with a whole bunch of references (some to smart cards, some to PKCS type libraries). It might be worthwhile reading the doco for your libraries.

Comment: The error reference to iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.wrapper library. I thought someone somehow encountered this error. Appearently not.. Thats why I didnt write any library names.

Comment: The error message is shown in the code available [here](https://github.com/mikma/pkcs11wrapper/blob/6916293da907001e1ec835449de796ee2c5055ad/src/native/common/pkcs11wrapper.c). It talks about includes that "...the implementations of the connect and disconnect functions, which load/bind and unbind/unload the native PKCS#11 module." I'd be tempted to poke around the docs or [Programmer Manual](https://github.com/mikma/pkcs11wrapper/blob/android/docs/ProgrammerManual.pdf) to see what you can find out.